# Java - Capture value from text box, store in array and return max value in an output field

Tags: java, arrays, loops

So I have been asked to help my friend with a small java project, I have a decent enough idea about programming from using VBA but not enough to help him, Im not too clued up on Java

Basically, he has a form with a text box, 2 buttons and an output field

The text box is for entering a value - when he clicks one button, it has to store the value within the text box to an array - and the other button is to output the max value within the array - I would appreciate any help with this if possible

Many thanks,
Sean

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. Please provide us with code snippets of what you have tried.

Answer (score -1):

To me it sounds like homework. Since you didn't bother posting any code you have written yourself I will outline what I would do. You could use the getText() from a JTextField and store the output in a String. Then you could split that string by white space, provided it only contains integers. After this I would call the Integer.parseInt() method while iterating over the array. Be careful as the input in the box must be only integers, otherwise your program will throw exceptions.